# VPN Authentication Credentials (Local/Remote Identifiers) For Remote Access VPN

Tags: vpn, sonicwall

So I am trying to set up a remote access VPN using the free ShrewSoft vpn client:

https://www.shrew.net/software

I want to use a PSK as the authentication mechanism combined with XAuth so that a connection requires a valid username/pass combo. Under the authentication tab this particular VPN Client however is asking for a Local Identity and a Remote Identity.

The options for Local Identity Type are:

```
Fully Qualified Domain Name
User Fully Qualified Domain Name
IP Address
Key Identifier
```

The options for Remote Identity are:

```
Any
Fully Qualified Domain Name
User Fully Qualified Domain Name
IP Address
Key Identifier
```

My current thinking is that I can use the Fully Qualifed Domain Name provided by the remote firewall for the Remote Identity, but I do not know what it wants for local identity.

Just to stress: I am not trying to set up a site to site VPN.

Can anybody shed any light on what I am missing here? A screenshot can be provided if that would be helpful.

The current error I am getting during the connection is:

```
IKE Responder: Proposed IKE ID mismatch
```